# Meteor: is there any way to preserve not only DOM node during re-rendering, but its attributes too to work with Masonry?

Tags: meteor, rendering, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

Pre-history: I have a huge collection of items. Each item has some attributes. On the main page these items are arranged by Masonry and everything goes OK until one item is changed. After that, Meteor re-renders all of them, erasing all attributes. This causes elements to stack on the left. If I run Masonry in the `rendered`, it helps, but page blinks after each update (as elements go left first and only after that is being arranged).

I've explored the `preserved` option. It's pretty helpful, but does not help since it does not preserve DOM node's attributes (including styling and its current position set by Masonry in particular).

I've made a simple test for demonstration purposes at [preserve-test.meteor.com](http://preserve-test.meteor.com/) . In this test I have a collection with one item, whose value is displayed. You can toggle DOM node's visibility by clicking the 'Toggle visibility' button and change item's value by clicking the 'Update item' button.

Wait till the page loads and 'Here is a number' label appears. Click on the first button. The label should disappear. Click on the second button. Label appears again with different value, while I expect it to silently update its text and keep the 'hidden' attribute. Here's the problem: when collection item is updated, DOM node's styles are erased, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to preserve dynamically set attributes of a DOM node while using Meteor's reactivity? Here is a code of the example:

preserve-test.html:

```
<head><title>preserve-test</title></head>
<body>{{> hello}}</body>

<template name="hello">
  <div><input type="button" id="toggle" value="Toggle visibility" /></div>
  <div><input type="button" id="update" value="Update item" /></div>
{{#if item}}
  {{> some_item item }}
{{else}}
  Loading, please wait...
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="some_item">
  <div id="some_item">
    Here is a number: {{value}}
  </div>
</template>
```

preserve-test.js:

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.item = function () {
    return Items.findOne();
  };

  var node = null;
  Template.some_item.rendered = function() {
    if (!node) {
      node = $(this.find('#some_item'));
    }
  }


  Template.some_item.preserve({
    '#some_item': true
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click #toggle' : function () {
      $(node).toggle();
    },
    'click #update': function() {
      Items.update(Items.findOne()._id, {$inc: { value: 1}});
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Items.remove({});
    Items.insert({ value: 0 });
  });
}
```

Comment: please let me know if you find way, as I am about to work on the same architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current release, no. You can't have a region of code that uses Meteor's reactivity while also preserving attributes, etc added by other libraries. Meteor's rendering engine is currently being rewritten as Meteor UI which will have a more fine-grained approach to this, and should work with what you're trying to achieve. If you would like to try out the current preview of the new template engine, run your meteor app with:

```
meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5
```

I recommend reading and watching this blog post relevant to this issue:

http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/11/07/david-greenspan-at-devshop-9-meteors-new-rendering-model